# How do I use a switch statement to rearrange JComboBoxes?

Tags: java, swing, calendar, jcombobox

I am creating a calendar program that will allow someone to either convert from the Darian(Mars) calendar to the standard Julian calendar and vice verse. What I am looking to do is be able to switch the order of the JComboboxes depending on which way you want to convert the calendar. Thanks for any help that can be given. I am still pretty new to java and programming in general.

```
package com.cw.dc;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String[] calendarSelector = { "Darian(Martian Standard) to Julian", "Julian(Euro/Amero Standard) to Darian" };
    JComboBox<String> csList = new JComboBox<>(calendarSelector);
    JLabel csText = new JLabel();
    static String[] darianMonths = { "Sagittarius", "Dhanus", "Carpicornus", "Makara", "Aquarius", "Kumbha", "Pisces", "Mina",
            "Aries", "Mesha", "Taurus", "Rishabha", "Gemini", "Mithuna", "Cancer", "Karka", "Leo", "Simha", "Virgo",
            "Kanya", "Libra", "Tula", "Scorpius", "Vrishika" };
    static JComboBox<?> darianList = new JComboBox<Object>(darianMonths);
    static JLabel darianText = new JLabel();
    static String[] julianMonths = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December" };
    static JComboBox<?> julianList = new JComboBox<Object>(julianMonths);
    static JLabel julianText = new JLabel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main fr = new Main();
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Main() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(400, 300);
        setTitle("Darian/Julian Calendar");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Calendar Selector
        csList.setSelectedIndex(1);
        csList.addActionListener(this);
        add(csList);
        add(csText);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == csList) {
            JComboBox<?> cb = (JComboBox<?>) e.getSource();
            String msg = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
            switch (msg) {
            case "Julian(Euro/Amero Standard) to Darian":
                //csText.setText("1");
                    JtoD();
                break;
            case "Darian(Martian Standard) to Julian":
                //csText.setText("2");
                    DtoJ();
                break;
            default:
                csText.setText("Error");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void JtoD() {
        // Julian List
        julianList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        julianList.addActionListener(julianList);
        (julianList).setSelectedItem(julianList);
        (julianText).setLabelFor(julianText);

        // Darian List
        darianList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        darianList.addActionListener(darianList);
        (darianList).setSelectedItem(darianList);
        (darianText).setLabelFor(darianText);

        return;
    }

    private static void DtoJ() {
        // Darian List
        darianList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        darianList.addActionListener(darianList);
        (darianList).setSelectedItem(darianList);
        (darianText).setLabelFor(darianText);

        // Julian List
        julianList.setSelectedIndex(1);
        julianList.addActionListener(julianList);
        (julianList).setSelectedItem(julianList);
        (julianText).setLabelFor(julianText);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do meant by switching order of JComboboxes  ? Give an example for clarification

Comment: I think you have forgotten to add the JComboBoxes **darianList** and **julianList** to the container. When I run this code, the only thing I can see is the calendarSelector combo box.

Comment: Also you have another faults. For example you have added `julianList` as the `actionListener` to itself! The same is happened for `darianList`. I can not understand what you have wanted to do.

Comment: I am trying to have it where you use the top drop down menu to switch from darian to julian or julian to darian. And STaefi I noticed that after I posted it, but I have not yet fixed it. Like I said I am every new to java.